# CALayer thin white lines

Tags: xcode, animation, calayer, caanimation

I am animating a CALayer to move and for some reason I keep getting these thin white lines all across the screen... it's not my device I can assure you here is how I set up the CALayer:

```
dodgelayer=nil;
dodgelayer= [CALayer layer];
dodgelayer.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor].CGColor;

dodgelayer.frame = CGRectMake(190, 80, 50, 50);
dodgelayer.borderColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
dodgelayer.borderWidth = 2.0;
dodgelayer.cornerRadius = 50.0;
```

and how I animate it:

```
        CAKeyframeAnimation *anim = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];

      values = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint: CGPointMake(aLayer.frame.origin.x+25,aLayer.frame.origin.y+25)], [NSValue valueWithCGPoint: CGPointMake(point.x,point.y)], nil];
        [anim setValues:values];
        [anim setDuration:0.7];
        anim.removedOnCompletion=NO;
        anim.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
        anim.timingFunction=[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
        sublayer.shouldRasterize=YES;
        [sublayer addAnimation:anim forKey:@"position"];
```

I honestly have no idea what is making these thing white lines appear, but I can tell you that they appear during animations... im stumped on this one any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just bumped into this problem myself.
The cause is the shouldResterize = YES.
Before calling this, you should set

sublayer.rasterizationScale = [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale];

and the lines will go away.